# Creating a Script for moving data from one worksheet to another worksheet based on meeting criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have added pictures to help explain my scenario.

Please look at images "Place Data Into" & "Master Data".

My plan is to write a script to automatically fill cells(E6:K6) on "Place Data into" from "Master Data" Worksheet, based on meeting criteria inputted on to the "Master Data" Worksheet.

The criteria that it needs to meet or match from the "Master Data" for it to auto fill so to speak on to "Place Data Into" is the information in cell B6 in worksheet "Place Data Into" and the build number in merged cell F2 within "Place Data Into". The cells where this information can be found on the "Master Data" worksheet are in Cells C & Q.

But I only want it to move this data into the "Place Data Into" worksheet once a date has been entered into Cell column N on the "Master Data" worksheet.

Currently, it is a manual process and we want to automate it. Where can I get guidance on creating this code? I feel this is a mission to create!

Kind Regards

Steve

[Place Data Into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM3hI.png)

[Master Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdmfQ.jpg)

Comment: I need it to move over and not to disappear once the data has gone from the "Master Data" worksheet. The Data on the "Master Data" does not need to stay there once the column N has data in it.

Comment: Check out [`onEdit(e)` triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and the [`Range` class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of `SpreadsheetApp` in Apps Script - specifically the [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) methods. This should get you started.

Comment: Also, I suggest you delete your question. Aside from the fact that Stackoverflow is a forum for help to be sought when you've *already tried some code and have hit a roadblock*, I also suspect that certain people wouldn't like their names to be visible in the screenshot of the Spreadsheet where their names weren't fully blacked-out.